# What's the easiest way to convert a CSV file into a SQL database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv

I've got a CSV file that I have to analyse using SQL, so the first thing that I have to do is convert the CSV file into a SQL file. I've already tried using free online converters, but these are only useful for small csv file...
Do you have any idea regarding what's the best way to convert the CSV file ?

Thanks

Comment: The answer depends on your engine, and you've tagged multiple. What sql flavor are you *actually* using?

Comment: Turning a CSV file into a *database* seems unlikely to ever work.  You could use whatever data you have and load the data into a *table*.

Comment: I'm using Postgres & PSequel on OSX

Comment: Yes, I'm looking to load that in a table, sorry for the lack of accuracy

Comment: provide a few lines of your CSV file and also the definition of your SQL table. Also a rough idea of how many lines are on your CSV file

Comment: It's a basic comma separated table with headers (time, distance, origin, destination), I'd like to put it in an sql table as I need to filter some data that is also in other SQL tables

Comment: Can't you just build insert queries in file : "INSERT INTO (your columns) VALUES(" at the beginning of each line and ");" at the end ?

Comment: In my opinion, this question is too broad. You haven't said whether you already know the data types of the values in the CSV, or whether the table you want to populate is already defined (the alternative being that you are free to define it however you like). That being said, in broad strokes, a roll-your-own solution involves reading the data in using Python's included `csv` module and writing the data using `pyodbc` (or a more specific interface to your database if one is available; though the programming will be pretty much the same regardless due to PEP 249).

Comment: @Johnny_H do you know that `INSERT` can handle multiple rows and it's very inefficient to insert every row one by one?

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Since we don't know CSV file size, search/replace with regex can be the fastest way to process, even if it's inefficient for a big file.

Comment: @Johnny_H you can always process it in batches i.e. 1000 rows per insert

Answer (score 1):

The query with COPY would be something like this.

```
COPY $tableName FROM '/path/to/file.csv' DELIMITER ',' CSV HEADER
```

Comment: I was going to say that @Bentaye xD

Answer (score 0):

A naive approach

- Assuming all your columns are strings (if not, modify accordingly)
- Assuming you know the data in the CSV file is safe (no fear of SQL injection)

Once you have read your csv, manually create an insert statement.

Given the following csv

```
value11,value12,value13
value21,value22,value23
```

You could do that

```
# Read the CSV file in an array
rows = ["value11,value12,value13",
        "value21,value22,value23"]

valuesArray = []
for row in rows:
    sql = "('"
    sql += "','".join(row.split(","))
    sql += "')";
    valuesArray.append(sql)

values = ",".join(valuesArray)
sql = "INSERT INTO mytable(column1,column2,column3) VALUES"
sql += values + ";"
print(sql)
```

outputs

```
INSERT INTO mytable(column1,column2,column3) VALUES
('value11','value12','value13'),
('value21','value22','value23');
```

Comment: Although you automate a part inserting every row with a own statement is very inefficient.

Comment: yeah I said naive approach :) Also I am new to python so I don't know all the tricks in the box.

Comment: Please read https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/sql-insert.html - specifiacally `To insert multiple rows using the multirow VALUES syntax` to make it efficient and also https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_injection.asp - so that was the last time in your life when you built SQL query by concatenating strings.

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Appreciate the input. Modified to use multirow insert (stupid mistake). Also I assume what is in the CSV file is safe and he knows what he is importing

Comment: Never assume such things

Comment: @ElmoVanKielmo Fair enough, I added a disclaimer saying that it is assumed in my answer.